# How to set height and width of a new window from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, tabs, popup

I have been trying this from hours that I am opening a new window and I am bound to launch from code behind so it is not opening in new tab.
I want to adjust the height and width of this window, but I am unable to set the same.
I also tried calling a javascript function from code behind and writing the same in aspx page, but no luck.

I am posting my code:
From Code behind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), scriptKey, "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('../ReportWebForm.aspx?ReportType=Report','height=50,width=2000,left=0px,top=0px,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes');</script>");
```

if I launch from server by calling aspx page javascript:

```
 function OpenWindow() {
        window.parent.open('../ReportWebForm.aspx?ReportType=Report', 'width = 100%, height = 100%');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

note 2nd parameter is name of window. the height and width you need to give in 3rd parameter

```
 function OpenWindow() {
        window.open('../ReportWebForm.aspx?ReportType=Report','', 'width = 100, height = 100');
    }
```

Comment: I did the same but no success. :(

Comment: have you tried giving height and width as px values and not %

Comment: by anychance your scenario includes iframe and cross domain communication ?

Comment: Just got it running, the name was same with another one. It worked when I gave second parameter unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  <a href="javascript:;" style="color:#000"  onClick="window.open('printreport3.php','msgWindow','toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, top=30, left=100, width=1000, height=auto')"> Print View </a>
```

you have to set scrollbar to yes. `scrollbars=yes`