# JavaScript converted window.showModalDialog to window.open how to resize?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript below. How do i resize window.open to make it smaller and match the size of the modal pop up?

```
window.showModalDialog("*some code*;");
```

to

```
  window.open("*some code*;");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set height and width of a new window from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543971/how-to-set-height-and-width-of-a-new-window-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/','',' scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,width=500, resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2

```
window.open("", "", "width=400,height=400");
```

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open width AND height should be set, or the behaviour might not be as expected.

Comment: @ChopSuey what is the problem ? Add height in params. I edited the answer and added example of w3schools and copied the code line here as well. Width setting the height and width for the model